# Securing a data service gateway communications

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, nodes

I have a number of applications where i want users to be able to access their own accounts across all of them.
I thought about using 1 database but it just seems better to keep them all separate.

The flow i have settles on is user has an account on SITE_A but they use a custom sso login on SITE_B which calls back to SITE_A and gives permission to the endpoint to use a separate API which copies the users profile from SITE_A over to SITE_B.

This API essentially stitches the other APIs in SITE_A + SITE_A

what is the best way to secure this special API, it offers kind of god mode if an account logs in then we can move its data across servers.

What is the best way to make this secure ?

Users login and get a JWT, maybe the calls between the APIs should maybe have some separate kind of token as its internal

Comment: "it just seems better to keep them all separate" - why? Keeping them in sync will be quite fiddly; you seem to really be looking for a single sign-on (SSO) system, where the user information is in one database/app only.

Comment: Because the different applications do different things, i am also afraid that if a hack happens then there is 1 point of failure

Comment: In your scheme, one service being hacked would also give the attacker a copy of the user database.

Comment: its true, but aside from that it is multiple products which do very different things, the database would be extremely clunky if it had everything for all apps

Comment: Read up on what single sign-on does? You don't need to store and copy user (login) information between databases.

Comment: i know what SSO is, the problem is that each of these products is so vastly different from one another, the SSO is easy to setup the problem is that they will have different profiles/settings on each of the platforms so i need a way to sync them, honestly i dont think it makes sense to have such vastly different platforms feeding off the same database